# routerlink instead of (click) for ionic4/angular8

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I developed a component which works fine so far. In that component i wanted to use a forward link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail/'] + translation.term" routerDirection="forward">
      <ion-label style="cursor: pointer;">{{translation.term}}</ion-label>
</a>
```

The console reports:  **Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.**

This is the components.module.ts, which should 'support' all my components.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header/header.component';
import {TransitemComponent} from './transitem/transitem.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// import needed, if any component uses ionic tags
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

// Translation service
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [HeaderComponent, TransitemComponent],
    imports: [IonicModule, TranslateModule.forChild(), CommonModule], // import needed, if any component uses ionic tags
    exports: [HeaderComponent, TransitemComponent]
})

export class ComponentsModule {}
```

How can I employ the routerlink without errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the RouterModule to have routerLink available. It also looks like you want `[routerLink]="['/detail/' + translation.term]"`.